# How can I parse a XML file with a list of nodes?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-sql, windows-runtime, linq-to-xml

if I have a simple xml file like

```
<person>
  <age>46</age>
  <name>Max</name>
</person>
```

I can use XDocument and LinqToSQL to read the data into my structure:

```
var res = from item in xdoc.Descendants("person")
          select new Person
          {
              Age = item.Element("age").Value,
              Name = item.Element("name").Value,
          };
```

But now I have more then one element, for example

```
<person>
  <age>46</age>
  <name>Max</name>
  <phone>123</phone>
  <phone>456</phone>
</person>
```

How can I now pare the document and read the data into my structure? Because now I need a list of strings, but how do I get every phone line and add it to my list?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any evidence of LINQ to SQL in there... that's *just* LINQ to XML as far as I can see. And when you say "more than one element" you're *just* talking about the `phone` element, right?

Comment: Hi! Do you have the XSD or some kind of scheme definition for the XML Files available? Kr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* you're just looking for:

```
var res = from item in xdoc.Descendants("person")
          select new Person
          {
              Age = item.Element("age").Value,
              Name = item.Element("name").Value,
              Phones = item.Elements("phone").Select(x => x.Value).ToList()
          };
```

I would make `Age` an integer though (or ideally represent the birth date as a `DateTime` instead, but...), and probably use the explicit conversion rather than the `.Value` property:

```
var res = from item in xdoc.Descendants("person")
          select new Person
          {
              Age = (int) item.Element("age"),
              Name = (string) item.Element("name"),
              Phones = item.Elements("phone").Select(x => (string) x).ToList()
          };
```

All of this assumes that your `Person` class has a writable `Phones` property of type `IList<string>` or something similar.

Comment: Thank you. If the phone tag was something like this <phone type='home'>123</phone>. How do I get both information and save it to my type telephone?

Comment: @ThomasSebastianJensen: Then you'd need something like `.Select(x => new Telephone((string) x.Attribute("type"), (string) x)`